# Not able to install haxm in azure vm

Tags: android, azure, android-emulator, haxm

I am trying to install haxm in a windows azure vm (**vm size Ds2 v3 - docs state it supports nested virtualization**), but the haxm checktool states all condition satisfied except one **VMX Enabled - no**.

I am not sure how to enable the vmx for my root azure vm. General step to enable vmx for a physical machine is through bios settings is what i saw, but is this possible in azure vm.

Purpose of installating haxm is to run android emulator in my root azure vm.

Is this possible or i should create a nested vm inside my azure and then run android emulator inside the nested vm?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP6Ty.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not able to install haxm in azure vm.

`VMX` feature must be enabled in the **BIOS** of an `Azure VM` in order to run **HAXM** , However, the `BIOS` of an `Azure VM` is not accessible directly, so you cannot enable `VMX` through the `BIOS` settings.

I tried to install **HAXM** in an `Azure VM` running `Windows Server` with the **Ds2 v3 VM** size and Generation 2, but I'm also encountering the following error

[image]

If you need to run the `HAXM` inside an `Azure VM`,try to install the same in `Gen-1 Version` with same [Sizes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-new-dv3-and-ev3-vm-sizes/).

**VM Configiration**

[image]

When I try to install `HAXM` in an `Azure VM` with Generation 1, it works fine

[image]

**Successfully Installed HAXM in Azure VM.**

[image]

Reference: [Enable nested virtualization on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed description, by choosing Gen-1 i was able to install HAXM. But my bigger motive was to run android studio this is not running because of nested virtualization i believe, i am trying to figure out the issue wrt emulator. By any chance if you know how to run emulator inside azure vm kindly let me know.

Comment: If you select the [DSv2 image size](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-new-dv3-and-ev3-vm-sizes/), it will support nested virtualization by default. Once you create a nested VM, you can [enable nested virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization#configure-nested-virtualization) for the virtual machine.