powershell inside docker environment hangs at Azure Windows VM
Running the following command on Azure Windows VM
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 powershell
With the above command , the images is downloaded successfully , but never managed to initiate powershell , instead it failed with the following error:
docker: Error response from daemon: container 0c709eb12c2c65dcba4427e078ef6bd244c56a67b8a8e4b8c7ba4cfc1ad05866 encountered an error during hcs::System::Start: context deadline exceeded.
Any idea on how to address this issue ?

Hi @sajis997 ,  Its look Docker Desktop daemon service is not running properly, make sure to restart the docker desktop and check ,if still same issue, kindly update docker application.

Could it the reason that nested virtualization is not enabled on Azure VM ? If yes, how to enable it ?

Follow the Stack Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614055/not-able-to-install-haxm-in-azure-vm/76619309#76619309 about nested virtualization.

But above issue is not related to nested virtualization, its look like Docker desktop app issue, Kindly update and restart the application.


powershell inside docker environment hangs at Azure Windows VM

The error your encountered usually occurs due Docker daemon is unable to start the container within the default time limit.
This can happen due to several reasons such as insufficient space or conflicts with other running containers in docker.

Make sure that your system has enough space (CPU, memory, disk space) available to run the container. You can try stopping other running containers or freeing up resources to see if it resolves the issue.

Sometimes, restarting the Docker service or the VM can resolve container startup issues
Restart-Service docker


Ensure that Docker is up to date. Sometimes, issues are resolved in newer releases of Docker Desktop.

I have followed below steps to create same image.
I create a VM with Windows (Windows 10 Pro)

Setup Docker Desktop inside your Windows VM.
Once done, verify your docker desktop version and info
here look for OS type, ensure that OS type is windows as by default docker desktop installs with linux container. If you see OS type is showing as linux, change it to windows using
& $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon



refer doc
If it prompts you saying you need hyper V to be enabled, then enable the hyper V setup first
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All



This will restart the system, if system not restarted, you manually restart it and then login and verify
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object { $_.FeatureName -like "*Hyper-V*" -or $_.FeatureName -eq "Containers" }



and then re run
& $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon



Once done and you see

Then run your docker command
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 powershell



It will pull and extract and eventually run it


Reference:
https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim/issues/801
